# Why when drawBackground is called does it override the setBackgroundBrush colour?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm following this series on youtube [Node Editor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbTLhMJARrk&list=PLZSNHzwDCOggHLThIbCxUhWTgrKVemZkz). I'm attempting to learn both Qt and C++ at the same time, possibly a stupid idea, but "hello world" tutorials don't do much for me.

Episode 1 We are to create a grid using the drawBackground method, however before this in the class constructor we have set the background to a light grey colour. When I run the code without the drawBackground the scene shows the light grey background. However when I run it with the drawBackground method uncommented the grid is drawn but the background is now white.

Why does the drawBackground() method override the QDMGraphicsScene() setBackgroundBrush?

qdmgraphicsscene.h

```
#ifndef QDMGRAPHICSSCENE_H
#define QDMGRAPHICSSCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>

#include "math.h"

class QDMGraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
public:
    QDMGraphicsScene();

    //Settings
    QColor _colour_background, _colour_light, _colour_dark;
    QPen _pen_light, _pen_dark;
    int scene_width, scene_height, gridSize, gridSquares;
    QVector<QLine> lines_light, lines_dark;
    void drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect);
};

#endif // QDMGRAPHICSSCENE_H
```

qdmgraphicsscene.cpp

```
#include "qdmgraphicsscene.h"


QDMGraphicsScene::QDMGraphicsScene()
{
    this->gridSize = 60;
    this->gridSquares = 3;
    this->_colour_background = QColor(57,57,57);
    this->_colour_light = QColor(47,47,47);
    this->_colour_dark = QColor(41, 41, 41);


    this->_pen_light = QPen(this->_colour_light);
    this->_pen_light.setWidth(1);
    this->_pen_dark = QPen(this->_colour_dark);
    this->_pen_dark.setWidth(2);

    this->scene_width = 64000;
    this->scene_height = 64000;
    this->setSceneRect(-this->scene_width/2, -this->scene_height/2, this->scene_width, this->scene_height);

    this->setBackgroundBrush(this->_colour_background);
}

void QDMGraphicsScene::drawBackground(QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{

    //create grid
    int left = (int)floor(rect.left());
    int right = (int)ceil(rect.right());
    int top = (int)floor(rect.top());
    int bottom = (int)ceil(rect.bottom());

    int first_left = left - (left % this->gridSize);
    int first_top = top - (top % this->gridSize);

    //compute lines
    for(int x = first_left; x < right; x=x+this->gridSize){
        if(x % (this->gridSize * this->gridSquares) != 0){
            this->lines_light.append(QLine(x,top,x,bottom));
        } else {
            this->lines_dark.append(QLine(x,top,x,bottom));
        }
    }

    for(int y = first_top; y < bottom; y=y+this->gridSize){
        if(y % (this->gridSize * this->gridSquares) != 0){
            this->lines_light.append(QLine(left,y,right,y));
        } else {
            this->lines_dark.append(QLine(left,y,right,y));
        }
    }

    //draw lines
    painter->setPen(this->_pen_light);
    painter->drawLines(this->lines_light);

    painter->setPen(this->_pen_dark);
    painter->drawLines(this->lines_dark);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is simply that your `drawBackground` override doesn't use the background brush -- you just set the `QPainter` pen and use it to draw lines.

I think the simplest solution would be to call the base class implementation of `drawBackground` at the top of your own, so...

```
void QDMGraphicsScene::drawBackground (QPainter *painter, const QRectF &rect)
{

    /*
     * Call base class drawBackground implementation to draw background.
     */
    QGraphicsScene::drawBackground(painter, rect);

    //create grid
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: Ah ok I'll give that a whirl. I thought that my override would still run the virtual methods constructor.

Comment: Yup! that was it! Thanks for your help.